# Modification of constant data through pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have read that following code would be invalid and should issue error:

```
double rates[5] = {88.99, 100.12, 59.45, 183.11, 340.5};
const double locked[4] = {0.08, 0.075, 0.0725, 0.07};
double * pnc = rates; // valid
pnc = locked; // not valid
pnc = &rates[3]; // valid
```

`pnc` is pointer-to-double and user can't change data through it. Although, I compiled program adding this chunk of code:

```
printf("%f\n", *pnc);   
*pnc = 1000.0;
printf("%f\n", *pnc);
```

Visual Studio Community gave me warning C4090 (different 'const' qualifiers), but executed without problems. When I run program, output looks like this:

0.080000
1000.000000

Why can I do it even in case it has to be forbidden?

Comment: Because it is C, and you can basically do whatever you want to if you try hard enough.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yeah, it is really similar question to my doubts. Thanks for showing!

Comment: @MrDonMatti - A compiler can easily transform your code `*pnc = 1000.0;
printf("%f\n", *pnc);` into `printf("%f\n", 1000.0);` and produce the result *without* modifying any constants. Still undefined behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

The const qualifier is only to prevent compilation (or at least create a warning) if a dev modify an element that, in the program logic, should be constant. In fact, once it is compiled, in almost every case, const or not const, the generated program will be the same.

Here there is a warning, but because you are a crazy dev (we are all crazy sometime), you ignored it.

If you want, you can even do

```
pnc = (double *)locked;
```

**UPDATE:** You can look at this link for more details. It also speak about C++, but it's very interesting :)
http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm

Comment: Impressive trick! It caused that previous warning disappeared after adding this line.